# Animate segue and display keyboard together smoothly

Tags: ios, swift, animation, keyboard, segue

I have View Controller that accepts text input using an UITextView called "myTextView".

When I segue to myTextView, I use the following:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("myTextView", sender: self)
```

`myTextView` is presented. Then next the keyboard is displayed after `viewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.myTyping.becomeFirstResponder()        
}
```

Everything animates smoothly.   However I want the keyboard to display at the same time as the segue animating and being displayed together and not one after the other.

I can do that with the call for the keyboard with the segue call. However, the animation is jittery and choppy, and not smooth.

How can I both segue to myTextView View Controller and display the keyboard at the same time without any animation jitters?

Comment: Have you tried `self.myTyping.becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewWillAppear` method?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did try this in `viewWillAppear` but unfortunately the same thing. It would appear the combined keyboard and segue animation is jittery and choppy on A5 device, but when testing on A7 device, the issue doesn't appear to be evident.